CSS: Animation with a scrollbar?
Trying to use CSS animation for the first time.  This is just a simple HTML page with a story.  I just wanted to add a simple dripping animation over the page, which I have working nicely, but for some reason the animation code is interfering with my scrollbar code.  So, when I try to open the page in chrome, there's no scrollbar and no way to scroll down the page. There is only meant to be a vertical scrollbar.  Where is the problem?  Is there an inherent problem with having animation on a scrolling page?
Here's my code, the CSS:
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
        
}
section{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(redgothpeg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.blooddrops{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
}
.blooddrops div{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    filter: brightness(40%);
    
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(1){
    left: 2%;
    animation: animate 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -5s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(2){
    left: 5%;
    animation: animate 1.2s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -3s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(3){
    left: 21%;
    animation: animate 1.4s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -2s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(4){
    left: 13%;
    animation: animate 1.6s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -1s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(5){
    left: 45%;
    animation: animate 1.7s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -3s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(6){
    left: 92%;
    animation: animate 1.9s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -4s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(7){
    left: 9%;
    animation: animate 1.3s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -2s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(8){
    left: 19%;
    animation: animate 1.2s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -5s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(9){
    left: 29%;
    animation: animate 1.4s linear infinite;
    /* animation-delay: -1s; */
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(10){
    left: 39%;
    animation: animate 1.6s linear infinite;
    /* animation-delay: -3s; */
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(11){
    left: 49%;
    animation: animate 1.4s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -2s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(12){
    left: 52%;
    animation: animate 1.7s linear infinite;
    /* animation-delay: -2s; */
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(13){
    left: 69%;
    animation: animate 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -3s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(14){
    left: 79%;
    animation: animate 1.8s linear infinite;
    /* animation-delay: -4s; */
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(15){
    left: 89%;
    animation: animate 1.1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -1s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(16){
    left: 72%;
    animation: animate 1.3s linear infinite;
    /* animation-delay: -4s; */
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(17){
    left: 82%;
    animation: animate 1s linear infinite;
    /* animation-delay: -2s; */
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(18){
    left: 62%;
    animation: animate 1.6s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -4s;
}
@keyframes animate{
    0%{
        top: -10%;
            
}
    100%{
        top: 110%;
            
}
.set2:
    transform: scale(2.5);
    filter: blur(3px);
    filter: brightness(40$);
}

The HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" Href="bloody.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webfont/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
<style>
 :root{
     scrollbar-color: #ac5dfb #3c3c3c;
     scrollbar-width: thin;
     }
body {
  background-color: #FFFF;
  background-position:center;
  /* background-image:url(gothicpegHDghost.jpg); */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  /*overflow:scroll;*/
 
}
body p {
    color: #FFF;
}
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 6px;
            height: 60px;
            background-color: #3C3C3C;
            opacity: 0.25;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: #ac5dfb;
            border-radius: 8px;
            opacity: 0.5;
        } 
body p {
    font-family: Bradley Hand ITC;
}
body p {
    /*color: #ac5dfb;*/
    color: #9c5dfb;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    /*text-shadow: 2px 4px 8px #306;*/
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px #9a53e1;
}

}
</style>



@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
        
}
section{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(redgothpeg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.blooddrops{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
}
.blooddrops div{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    filter: brightness(40%);
    
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(1){
    left: 2%;
    animation: animate 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -5s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(2){
    left: 5%;
    animation: animate 1.2s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -3s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(3){
    left: 21%;
    animation: animate 1.4s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -2s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(4){
    left: 13%;
    animation: animate 1.6s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -1s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(5){
    left: 45%;
    animation: animate 1.7s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -3s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(6){
    left: 92%;
    animation: animate 1.9s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -4s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(7){
    left: 9%;
    animation: animate 1.3s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -2s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(8){
    left: 19%;
    animation: animate 1.2s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -5s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(9){
    left: 29%;
    animation: animate 1.4s linear infinite;
    /* animation-delay: -1s; */
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(10){
    left: 39%;
    animation: animate 1.6s linear infinite;
    /* animation-delay: -3s; */
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(11){
    left: 49%;
    animation: animate 1.4s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -2s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(12){
    left: 52%;
    animation: animate 1.7s linear infinite;
    /* animation-delay: -2s; */
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(13){
    left: 69%;
    animation: animate 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -3s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(14){
    left: 79%;
    animation: animate 1.8s linear infinite;
    /* animation-delay: -4s; */
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(15){
    left: 89%;
    animation: animate 1.1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -1s;
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(16){
    left: 72%;
    animation: animate 1.3s linear infinite;
    /* animation-delay: -4s; */
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(17){
    left: 82%;
    animation: animate 1s linear infinite;
    /* animation-delay: -2s; */
}
.blooddrops div:nth-child(18){
    left: 62%;
    animation: animate 1.6s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: -4s;
}
@keyframes animate{
    0%{
        top: -10%;
            
}
    100%{
        top: 110%;
            
}
.set2:
    transform: scale(2.5);
    filter: blur(3px);
    filter: brightness(40$);
}
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" Href="bloody.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webfont/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
<style>
 :root{
     scrollbar-color: #ac5dfb #3c3c3c;
     scrollbar-width: thin;
     }
body {
  background-color: #FFFF;
  background-position:center;
  /* background-image:url(gothicpegHDghost.jpg); */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  /*overflow:scroll;*/
 
}
body p {
    color: #FFF;
}
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 6px;
            height: 60px;
            background-color: #3C3C3C;
            opacity: 0.25;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: #ac5dfb;
            border-radius: 8px;
            opacity: 0.5;
        } 
body p {
    font-family: Bradley Hand ITC;
}
body p {
    /*color: #ac5dfb;*/
    color: #9c5dfb;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    /*text-shadow: 2px 4px 8px #306;*/
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px #9a53e1;
}

}
</style>
<title>Welcome To The REAL Nightmare...</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="blooddrops">
            <div><img src="blooddrop2.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop1.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop2.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop1.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop1.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop2.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop1.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop2.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop1.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop2.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop1.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop2.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop1.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop2.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop1.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop2.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop1.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop2.png" alt="" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="blooddrops set2">
            <div><img src="blooddrop2.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop1.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop2.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop1.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop1.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop2.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop1.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop2.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop1.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop2.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop1.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop2.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop1.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop2.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop1.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop2.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop1.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div><img src="blooddrop2.png" alt="" /></div>
        </div>
            <div align="center">
  <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center">
        <p><img src="https://wallpapers.com/images/featured/dark-carnival-p0uedke6wpqp6q3d.jpg" width="90%" height="90%" /></p>
        <audio controls autoplay>
          <source src="crylittlesister.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        <p align="center">Your browser does not support the audio element. </p>
  </audio></div> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p align="center"><em><font color="#750ad3">The scene opens inside a hospital room, with the ambience of the hospital intercoms over doctors and nurses moving about and talking to each other outside. The camera zooms in on the chart at the foot of the bed and the name of the patient lying there within: &quot;ANDREW HUTTMAN.&quot; The camera pans up with a view of the heart monitor....</font></em></p>
      <p align="center"><em><font color="#750ad3"><img src="https://bpb-eu-w2.wpmucdn.com/reflect.ucl.ac.uk/dist/5/522/files/2019/03/gif-2mcl7ay.gif" width="410" height="230" /></font></em></p>
      <p align="center">Suddenly, the lights go out. Out from the shadows beside the bed walks Solom Noctourne. He sits on the foot of the bed and addresses the camera...</p>
      <p align="left"><strong>Solom: </strong>Nightmare? Really, Bryan? What kind of &quot;nightmare&quot;, do you suppose you are, <em>boy</em>?  From where I'm standing, you're about as much of a 'nightmare' as a jolly circus clown to <em>KINDERGARDENER</em>! You know, it really pisses me off how you walk around throwing that moniker around while never even remotely living up to it! You're no nightmare, you're a f@$#ing <em>JOKE</em>!  I would call you the Dynasty's weakest link, but I suppose that role belongs to your feeble brother here, doesn't it? I'll say this, you've certainly got guts, knowing damn well the onslaught that you're walking into on X-Rated. Yet I do believe you'll actually show up. You got more guts than brains, kid1 You want a nightmare, I'll show you a <em>real </em>nightmare! HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA!!!!</p>
      <p align="center"><em>Solom stands up and walks passed the camera. The camera then pans back up to the heart monitor screen....</em></p>
      <p align="center"><em><img src="heartflatline.jpg" width="640" height="360" /></em></p>
      <p align="center">BEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEP</p>
      <p align="center">The monitor flatlines; doctors and nurses rush into the room as the lights come back on...</p>
      <p align="left"><strong>Nurse: </strong>CODE BLUE! CODE BLUE! WE NEED HELP IN HERE! DOCTOR! </p>
      <p align="left"><strong>Doctor: </strong>WE'RE LOSING HIM!!!! </p>
      <p align="center"><em>The doctors and nurses continue trying CPR and defibulating, to bring the patient back from the brink of death... The long tone of the rhythmless heart monitor echoes into the night as the scene fades out with the laughter of Solom Noctourne echoing through the shadows...</em></p>
      <p align="center"><img src="creepycut.gif" width="353" height="316" /></p>
      <p align="center"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1e/6c/55/1e6c5590770c28f09c8761937e6238b7.jpg" /></p>
      <p align="center"><em>The  next scene opens in the dead of night, just outside a creepy looking carnival. A man walks towards the entrance, and as he gets near, we can see it's Bryan Huttman.  He stops at the entrance to look around, as Solom speaks from the ether...</em></p>
      <p align="left"><strong>Solom: </strong>Welcome, to the Dark Carnival, Bryan Huttman! Hahahahahahahaha!</p>
      <p align="left"><strong>Bryan: </strong>Man, f@$# this s@$#. I'm outta here.</p>
      <p align="center"><em>Bryan turns and tries to walk away, but some unseen force sucker punches him in the face, knocking him back onto the seat of his pants on the ground...</em></p>
      <p align="left"><strong>Bryan: </strong>...the hell? Who's there?!</p>
      <p align="center"><em>Hearing no reply, Bryan gets back to his feet and starts trying to walk away again, only to get sucker punched by the ether once again. Back on the ground once again, he spits out some blood and starts getting pissed..</em></p>
      <p align="left"><strong>Bryan:</strong> Aight Solom, you want me to go into your sh!#y carnival, fine. But, I'm gonna whoop your dark a$$ when I find you, muthaf@$#a! </p>
      <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>      
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>




Could you show the relevant HTML and preferably create a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

There isn't a lot to begin with so I added all the code in the example snippet thing.  You can also see the uploaded page here:
https://noctourne.x10.mx/solomrp27.html
